# SpeechRecognition API not stopping on React application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, webapi

I am trying to add speech recognition to my web application. I am using Web Api's speech recognition. This is my react's code:

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import React from 'react';
import { Typography, Button, Box } from '@mui/material';

function App() {
  const [values,setValues] = React.useState("Click on the start button and start speaking.");
  var SpeechRecognition = window.SpeechRecognition || window.webkitSpeechRecognition;
  var recognition = new SpeechRecognition();
  recognition.continuous = true;
  recognition.lang = 'en-US';
  recognition.interimResults = true;
  
  recognition.onresult = function(event) {
    console.log("Value is "+event.results[0][0].transcript)
    setValues(event.results[0][0].transcript)
  }
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Typography align='center' variant="h1">
        Filler word helper
      </Typography>

      <Box sx={{
        backgroundColor:'gray',
        maxWidth:'md',
        margin:'auto',
        minHeight:200,
      }}>
        <Typography style={{
          paddingLeft:'2%',
          paddingRight:'2%'
        }} color="white">
          {values}
        </Typography>
      </Box>

      <Box sx={{
        display:'flex',
        justifyContent:'space-around',
        paddingTop:'2%'
      }}>
        <Button 
        onClick={()=>{
          recognition.start()
        }}
        variant="contained"
        >Start</Button>

        <Button 
        onClick={()=>{
          setValues("Click on the start button and start speaking.")
        }}
        variant="contained"
        >Clear</Button>

        <Button 
        onClick={()=>{
          recognition.abort()
          recognition.stop()
          console.log("Stop pressed")
        }}
        variant="contained"
        >Stop</Button>

      </Box>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The problem is that after I start the process I cannot stop it. It keeps on going. I did try stopping and aborting and trying various combinations.

Can anyone help me with this issue ?

Answer (score 2):

The issue seems to be that you have set `continuous` to `true`.

---

This appears to always listen to the user, even when it has been aborted.

To fix this, you simply have to set it to `false`, as below.

```js
recognition.continuous = false;
```

Also, by default, `continuous` is set to `false`, so removing it will have the same result.

---

This should stop the `SpeechRecognition` API from listening continuously, and abort/stop when `abort()` and `stop()` are called.

Comment: I tried this but the process does not stop.